# Macbook Air 11-inch grey screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

MacBook Air 11-inch, Mid 2013 screen went grey after the upgrade. No Apple logo and when I connect it to the external screen it still shows grey but I can hear the chime sound when I power it on.

[image: Grey screen]

Comment: Which update? Have you tried the usual reset key command when booting: holding down CMD-P-R immidiately after pressing the power key? Does that work, i.e. does your MBA reboot in a loop hwile you hold those keys in? If so try to let the startup chime happen 3 times then let go and see if it boots normally. If not, try to shut down the MBA then hold down ALT/Option-CTRL and Shift, then while holding, press the power key for 2 seconds then let go. Now try to boot normally

Comment: OS update. I have tried that but still not working . Thanks